# StackOverFlowError When Applying Filter to a Stream

Tags: scala

The following code blows the stack:

```
val fibs: Stream[BigInt] = BigInt(0) #:: BigInt(1) #:: fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map { n => n._1 + n._2 }.takeWhile(x => x < 4000000).filter(x => x % 2 == 0)

scala> fibs foreach println
0
1
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

If I take out the filter and apply it to the stream in another expression as follows, it is fine:

```
scala> val fibs: Stream[BigInt] = BigInt(0) #:: BigInt(1) #:: fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map { n => n._1 + n._2 }.takeWhile(x => x < 4000000)
fibs: Stream[scala.math.BigInt] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> fibs filter ( x => x % 2 == 0)
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[scala.math.BigInt] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> fibs filter ( x => x % 2 == 0) foreach println
0
2
8
34
144
610
2584
10946
46368
196418
832040
3524578
```

Why does it blow the stack with the first approach but not the second?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with `filter` specifically but with a recursive definition that tries to both create and remove the next element in the sequence.  Consider the following.

```
scala> val fibs: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map(n => n._1 + n._2).filter(_ < 30)
fibs: Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> fibs(8)
res58: Int = 21

scala> fibs(9)
*<massive stack dump>*
```

As you can see, it's not the presence of `filter` but the attempt to access an element that the filter tries to remove.

Keep the recursive Stream definition simple. Apply filters and limits (`takeWhile`) outside of the definition.

Answer (score 0):

I can only give a superficial quick answer.

In the first case you have the `filter(x => x % 2 == 0)` inside the **recursive** stream, which leads to your problem. That is why `0` and `1` are printed, which does not happen in your second example, because you filter after the sequence is established. `1` is not even after all.

You should define your fib stream separately and only then apply filters.

```
val fibs: Stream[BigInt] = BigInt(0) #:: BigInt(1) #:: 
                             fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map { n => n._1 + n._2 }

val result = fibs.filter(_ % 2 == 0).takeWhile(_ < 4000000)
```

Comment: To me it shouldn't make a difference. What is about chaining the filter that makes it blow up? I expected the second expression to be equivalent to the first.